# Getting null project key in a Jira Cloud App sprint_started webhook

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I'm developing a Jira Cloud Add on that will receive sprint related events:

```
  "modules": {
    "webhooks": [
      {
        "event": "sprint_started",
        "url": "/sprints/started?project={project.key}&id={project.id}"
      },
      {
        "event": "sprint_closed",
        "url": "/sprints/closed?project={project.key}&id={project.id}"
      }
```

As [described in the documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/webhooks/) I've used the placeholders {project.key} and {project.id} to get the information about the project in which the event was triggered.

This is the controller that is invoked:

```
    @PostMapping(value = ["/started", "/closed"])
    fun sprintEvent(@AuthenticationPrincipal hostUser: AtlassianHostUser, @RequestParam project: String, @RequestParam id: String, @RequestBody body: Map<String, Any>): Mono<Void> {
```

**However both project and id are null**

The same thing for issue events works smoothly, receiving the project key:

```
  "modules": {
    "webhooks": [
      {
        "event": "jira:issue_created",
        "url": "/issues/created?project={project.key}&issue={issue.key}"
      },
```

```
    @PostMapping(value = ["/created", "/updated"])
    fun issueEvent(@AuthenticationPrincipal hostUser: AtlassianHostUser, @RequestParam project: String, @RequestParam issue: String, @RequestBody body: Map<String, Any>): Mono<Void> {
```

What's the problem with the sprint events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a limitation in which those properties aren't available in the sprint event "context".

My workaround was:

1. Get the board id:

```
val boardId = (body["sprint"] as Map<String, Any?>)["originBoardId"] as Int
```

2. Get the whole board information with the atlassian rest client:

```
val board = atlassianHostRestClients.authenticatedAsAddon().getForObject("/rest/agile/1.0/board/{boardId}", Map::class.java, boardId) as Map<String, *>`
```

3. Extract the project key from there:

```
val projectKey = (board["location"] as Map<String, *>)["projectKey"] as String
```